# Change form field color if the value has change

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm gettig a bit lost with some javascript logic.
I have a form with 3 text fields.
They show a default value through a javascript (no placeholder).
When the form is focused, the value is cleared and when the form is blurred, the default value is restored if the field value hasn't been change.

I have to write some conditional logic to ensure that the field text color is changed from grey (default placeholder value) to black if the value is changed.

The 3 fields have a different default value. I tried to write a general script on Blur to check the value of the current field to test it against the default value.

```
  $fields = $('#webform-component-group-1 .webform-component-watermarked');
  var keys = [];
  var values = [];
  console.log($fields.length);
  $fields.each(function(){
    keys.push($(this).attr('id'));
    values.push($(this).val());
    $(this).blur(function(){
      console.log($(this).val());
      console.log($(this).val() !== values[keys.indexOf($(this).attr('id'))]);
    });
  });
```

but my test always return true as the placeholder value is not restored when I run the test on blur.

What would be the best way to handle this problem?

Cheers

Comment: Can i ask why are you not using placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you could do it like this:

Assuming the following HTML

```
<div id='fields'>
    <input value='start1' class='placeholder' />
    <input value='start2' class='placeholder' />
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#fields input').each(function(){
    // Save initial placeholder values
    $(this).data('placeholder', $(this).val());
}).on("focus", function(){
    // Remove placeholder value and color on focus
    if( $(this).val() === $(this).data('placeholder') ){
        $(this).val('').removeClass('placeholder');
    }
}).on("blur", function(){
    // Restore placeholder on blur if input is empty
    if( $(this).val().length === 0 ){
        $(this).val($(this).data('placeholder')).addClass('placeholder');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
input.placeholder{
    color:#ccc;
}

input{
    color:#000;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uWPJC/

Comment: That would be the ticket. Unfortunately i'm working on a form which doesn't use placeholder attributes. There is custom script that check if the default value has been changed to emulate the placeholder behaviour. So the value of the field is only 0 when the the field is focused. I have to check the new value of the field against the old one but when i check on blur, the value is still 0.

Comment: I'm actually not using placeholder attributes here, either.  Just storing the initial value in a `data-*` attribute (via the jQuery functions), and using a CSS class called placeholder for the state where the "placeholder" text is active.  I just used the name 'placeholder'.  Where I check if the length is 0 on blur, you could also check if the text is the same as the `data-placeholder` attribute.

Comment: Yes sorry, i've commented too fast. I have problems so sort out  the existig script emulating the placeholder thing. I've tried your technique but as soon as I tab through, the fields text darken, even if the value hasn't changed. One other issue is that i don't have access to the markup. an deverything is really messy. So far i can't make it work. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problems.  Hopefully you can get it to work.  I'm changing the font color as soon as the field gets focus (also removing the value, if it is the default).  So if you modify it to change the font color only after the value has been modified, that might work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with this code , you will get what u looking for

```
    var pass1 = document.getElementById('password');
    var pass2 = document.getElementById('vpass');
    var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');
    var goodColor = "#66cc66";
    var badColor = "#ff6666";
        if(pass1.value == pass2.value){
               pass2.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
        }
        else{
               pass2.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
        }
```